# Load Spread based on default item selected in the combobox and reload on changing selected item (knockout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal-2.0

I want to load my page based on default item selected in the combobox and reload on changing selected item (knockout).

Currently what I am doing is loading the form on click of a button. Here is my code. Please suggest me as I am very new to knockout.

html:

```
<select data-bind="options : employeeList, optionsText : 'name', value : selectedEmployeeList"></select>
</span>
<button class="toolbar-button" data-bind="click : load, disable :loading">Load employee</button>
```

js:

```
var filterVM = function () {
    this.employeeList = ko.observableArray();
    this.selectedEmployeeList = ko.observable();
};

dataService.getEmployeeLists(this.viewData.EmployeeId).then(loadEmployeeLists).then(enableControls);

filterVM.prototype.load = function () {

    var selectedEmployeeList = this.selectedEmployeeList();
    var self = this;

    if (selectedEmployeeList) {
        disableControls();
        dataService.getEmployeeByEmployeeList(this.viewData.employeeId, selectedEmployeeList.id)
            .done(loadPEmployeeSpread);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your load function on change of selected value selectedEmployeeList
Add following code in constructor

```
this.selectedEmployeeList .subscribe(function(newValue) {
    //This function is going to get called on every change of the selectedEmployeeList 
    //Add here your code to load the page
}, this);
```

subscribe :- is facility provided by knockout that it tracks every change made in the subscribed variable and calls function on every change.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in html too? I tried this making newValue as patientsList but no luck.

Comment: Hey @Dnyanesh I played around it and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: No you need not make any change in html.